# All Names that has a 2 nxt to them

Tags: google-sheets

Sample Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CUh9wCRt-wcoeRrNTfMZwu6dhmn0GXmXI0ckfMneTAI/edit#gid=0

[image: Sample Data]

What I need is a list under each column of the people from Column A that has a "2" in the columns to the right of them as you see in the "Results" area of the sampel sheet.

I have tried VLOOKUP etc, but cannot get it to work and am running out of time :)

Comment: The question was improved, but still, please provide the data as text. Images should enhance parts of the question, not replace them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=bycol(B1:6,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,filter(A1:A6,Σ=2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thats great, only issue is that if I add anything to any other column it was say "N/A" on row 15, eg if I put something in F1  it says N/A on F15.. I could just use conditional formatting for that I guess?

Comment: Just wrap the ***filter*** condition in the formula with `ifna()` or `iferror()`